# Is there more efficient way to pull out JSON data from .onload() function?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm playing with REST API just to get a deeper understanding of it. 
What I have been researching for in last few days was "How to pull out data from .onLoad() JSON response and assign it to global variables?" By a coincidence I found article about what callback functions are. I decided to solve this problem by myself before I will ask on StackOverflow. Here is the thing.

I initiated normal procedure to get data from Star Wars API provider.
Then I created a function which will take response planet data and assign it to global variables (like name of the planet, climate and diameter). This variables will be a data provider for 3Dobject in THREE.js and it will be dictating behaviour. I did not want to try to put whole THREE.js code into the .onload() function because I think that would make a lot of mess later on.
Voila! Now I have all data what I wanted in global variables and I can start to focus on the next part of my webApp, however... What I did is it most efficent way to solve this problem? Is takeOut() function still kind of callback function? Even when I did not gave this as a parameter of .onload() function? Like request.onLoad(takeout) for example?

```
        //instance of request obj
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

        //open connection and GET data
        request.open("GET", "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/", true);

        //working with data respond
        request.onload = function(){
            data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            return takeOut(data.name, data.climate, data.diameter);
        }

        //send a request for data
        request.send();


        //function to take out data from JSON response
        var name;
        var climate;
        var diameter;
        function takeOut(x,y,z){
            name = x;
            climate = y;
            diameter = z;
            return name, climate, diameter;
        }
```

I want JSON response with planet object name, climate and diameter assigned to a global variables as a data provider for another function. Function pulled and assigned all data to a var but is it efficient? Is there quicker and less "time consuming" method for this? Can I do this somehow with XMLHttpRequest method inside .onLoad() without creating separate function just specially for pulling out and assigning data to variables?

Answer (score 2):

In your code takeOut is not really a callback function. A callback function is a function that is passed as an argument to another function that has closure on the calling scope (and therefore access the variables that exist in the calling scope).

To make it reusable and utilize callback function:

```
function retrieveData(cb){
 //instance of request obj
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

        //open connection and GET data
 request.open("GET", "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/", true);

        //working with data respond
 request.onload = function(){
   data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   return cb(data);
 }

        //send a request for data
 request.send();
}

retrieveData(function(data){
  //access data.name; data.climate
})
```

Comment: O Yes hemel. This is looks a way better and it seems to be more functionaly. Thank you for propose.